# An HDD is fast when read by dd, slow otherwise

Tags: hard-drive, drive, smart

After updating Ubuntu, I found that my non-root HDD become too slow. Just see the numbers:

```
pv /dev/sda > /dev/null
```

gives 200kb/s. Mounting it (takes a minute) and running

```
rsync -r /mnt/hdd2/ /tmp/111
```

gives the same 200kb/s. You would think the drive is dead, but

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/dev/null bs=4M
```

gives 20Mb/s. Unfortunately, I have no place to copy the whole image of that drive to rescue the data.

I am not sure if it happened immediately after upgrade or after running fstrim. Why can it be like that?

I have already checked:

- Smartctl - squeaky clean. Did run tests.
- BIOS is in AHCI mode
- I tried to set the scheduler to noop - no difference at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had shrinked the NTFS partition that was on that drive by 30%, created a second partition with btrfs and run fstrim on it. That immediately restored the speed.

Don't run fstrim on NTFS partition.